# Does soft layer maintain historical record for devices

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Does soft layer maintain historical record for devices. For eg: I want to know when a device was cancelled and for how many months the device was active and what was the invoice of the device for a particular month?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep that data is stored in softlayer. eg. you can get the invoices using this https://gist.github.com/underscorephil/5861175 just set the startdate and enddate

regarding when the object was cancelled I think that information is stored in the logs you try this method

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects

Also you can try getting the billing item of the device, you can get all the billing items of your account calling this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAllBillingItems

The billing item constain the data about when it was created and when it was cancelled for more information see:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Item

Regards